# Format database string column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to query the database row results is about 300,000 rows (growing).

The call is made from a controller in my main view ( MVC .net core)
One of the columns comes in this format:

- [      ] The cat is black
- [      ] here is the change
- [G     ] Some other text

I need to strip the [      ]  or [G      ]

Would I removed it at database level eg:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Text] =  Right([Text], LEN([Text]) - 8) 
FROM MyDatabase
```

This seems incorrect – although it works – I have to put a magic number 8. What if this changes in the future? Developers insist in not having numbers that have no meaning?

Or do it in the controller :

```
viewModel.List = data.Select(val => new ViewModel
                    {
                        Id = val. Id,
                        Name = val.Name,
                        Text = val.Text.Substring(val.Text.IndexOf(']'))
                    }).ToList();
```

If you can shade some light or have a better idea I would appreciate it.

Comment: This is very complicated as you might not know what happens in the future with the table or the code. I would recommend cleaning up the table, and work your magic when data gets inserted, unless those are not garbage

Comment: Thank you - but I cannot clear the database table as data is important. I have no access on how data or when is inserted.

Comment: I said clean up the data, not clear the data. If the data is important how can you clean it in a query or controller?

Comment: Ok sorry - when data is displayed on the view they dont want to see [G] or [] as it is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Understood. The question remain, is this data relevant? (referring to the [] or [G] Does it have to stay in the database. If so. Will the way this is stored change in the future? Can these characters be somewhere else in the text?

Comment: The [] or [G] will have to stay in the database. I don't think their position is likely to change. So they will always be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Then @Zohar have your answer. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your usage of `=` and `[]` It's a pretty safe guess that the database you're using is SQL Server.
In that case, you could do it in the database with `charindex` - instead of `8` use `charindex(']', [Text])`:

```sql
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Text] =  RIGHT([Text], LEN([Text]) - CHARINDEX(']', [Text])) 
FROM MyDatabase
```

Comment: Yes sorry - I am using SQL server

Comment: @Zohar the problem will remain, if there is data that did not start with a `[`, but there might be a `[` in the data somewhere else, it will remove relevant data that is not intentional. Doing this is dangerous, and should be avoided.

Comment: @Jaques this can be avoided using all kind of techniques, but the OP didn't specify data without the `[]` or `[G ]`, so...

Comment: I will try this solution, will let you  know if it gets approved. Thanks

Comment: Thank you  - it got approved :-)

Answer (score 1):

Safer alternative with [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) :

```
SELECT [Id],
       [Name],
       [Text] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Text], '[] ', ''), '[G ] ', '') 
FROM MyDatabase
```

or probably a bit more efficient in C# :

```
Text = val.Text.Replace("[] ", "").Replace("[G ] ", "")
```